# XHTML to XML XSLT conversion

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xhtml

I am doing a very simple xslt to convert a html page to a xml file.

But it appears to me that the starting point is not that straightforward to me.My first goal is to convert a `<html>` tag into a `<topic>` tag.

I did the following xslt:

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/> 
  </xsl:copy>  
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="html">
  <topic>
    <xsl:text> Conversion Test</xsl:text>
  </topic>
 </xsl:template>
```

However, now after I run this xslt, the result xml is purely of the same content of the original html page, it seems that the third template match that I wrote (to match the `<html>` tag) never gets hit.

The source html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>..</head>
   <body>...</body>
 </html>
```

Could experts help me a little here?

Comment: Can you give an example of your html? (especially any namespaces like `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`)

Comment: @DevNull, I updated my question with the source html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0:**

Try adding `xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to your `xsl:stylesheet` and changing your match to `match="x:html"`. (Note: you don't have to use "x"; you can choose anything you want.)

**XSLT 2.0:**

Either use the above method or replace the namespace prefix in your match(es) to "*" (`match="*:html"`). You could also add `xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to the `xsl:stylesheet`.

Comment: thank you, it worked! Yes, the html is actually xhtml and I am using XSLT1.0, after put in your suggested namespace, worked great:)

Comment: I updated the title to reflect the nature of the source document too.

Comment: @Kevin - You're very welcome. Also, if you don't want the namespace in your XML output, add `exclude-result-prefixes="#all"` to `xsl:stylesheet`. (Note: you can replace `#all` with `x` to exclude `x` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to remove the first template or make it more specific than matching every node with `node()`.

Comment: Are you saying remove the identity transform?

Comment: @lkuty, I did try removing the first template. Now the resulting xml is simply a big node of text without any markup. It contains all the text from the original html page.

Comment: I was wrong. I thought the first rule could be chosen insted of the third but in fact the default priority for a match pattern with an element is greater than `node()` and thus it could not be the problem. I just didn't think about NS.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of XSLT is to transform **XML** documents into other **XML** documents. HTML is not a XML document. While XHTML is XML, it is actually HTML reformulated so I'm just not sure what you want to do is easy or possible with XSLT.

Comment: So NOW you update the title :). That reflects my problem with this.