# I want to pull data from my XML file and use it as link

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces

this is my xml sheet-

```
<ErrorLog_list>
<error><download_list>/home/fes/logs/ErrorLog-20111109.gz</download_list></error>
<error><download_list>/home/fes/logs/ErrorLog-20111110.gz</download_list></error>
<error><download_list>/home/fes/logs/ErrorLog-20111114.gz</download_list></error>
</ErrorLog_list>
```

what I want to do is to create a link pointing to `error/download_list`

so I have used this tag

```
<a href="{ErrorLog_list/error/download_list}"><xsl:value-of select="Title"/></a><br/>
```

but it ain't working...

I realised that the problem may be because it is stated as- `xmlns attributes are not interpreted as attribute value templates`

My question is that how can I change my namespace to use the above method? any help would be appreciated.

Please ignore my negligence.
Thanks

Comment: I don't see any xmlns, but my answer here may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920450/xhtml-to-xml-xslt-conversion/7920612#7920612

Comment: xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"

Comment: but it aint working ..can you please suggest how can i use the XML as a href link

Comment: Do you have any xmlns in your XML? (Is that an accurate example of your XML?)

Comment: thank u for your time ..but that is not exact XML...i made a mistake in declaring the xmlns..also my stylesheet version was not declared correctly..but its done now...thanks Dev

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should have the whole XML document to make a complete answer but here is what I can say.

Since you write `<xsl:value-of select="Title"/>` but we can't see any `Title` element, I guess that we are in a template rule that matches on the element that contains `Title` and that contains `ErrorLog_list`.

So when you use the attribute value template `{ErrorLog_list/error/download_list}`, you attempt to get all `download_list` with XPath. I guess that the returned node set will be concerted to a string value and thus the first value of the node set will be used, not the others.

You should use a `for-each` or make a template rule that matches on `ErrorLog_list/error/download_list`. Also you could use an `xsl:attribute` inside the template rule body if you want to avoid using an attribute template value.

```
<xsl:template match="download_list">
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../../Title"/>
    </a>
</xsl:template>
```